# Redis `keys` and reactive programming

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I know `keys` command should be avoided in Redis because it's an expensive opperation.

But what if I'm using reactive driver (Lettuce) in reactive programming (Spring Data Redis Reactive), where the `keys` returns a Flux? Would this still be a "problem"?

*Obs.: this is not a real situation for me. I'm just trying to understand the correct behaviour, since I've just started with reactive stuff.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ReactiveRedisTemplate.html#keys-K-), `scan` is still preferable to `keys` even in reactive environment:

> IMPORTANT: It is recommended to use ReactiveRedisOperations.scan() to
> iterate over the keyspace as ReactiveRedisOperations.keys(Object) is a
> non-interruptible and expensive Redis operation.

The problem with `keys` is not really on client side, it's rather on Redis side. That's why a reactive client doesn't really make a difference in this case. Although, `scan` is also better for reactive client because it can request new keys on demand respecting backpressure.

But you have a valid point, it's a bit confusing that `keys` returns `Flux`. Based on the semantic of the Redis command I'd rather expect a `Mono<List>` as return type.